# Are there any purposes for the management folder in Django other than commands?

Tags: django, django-manage.py

Why are management commands not in their own app-level folder? Are there other items which can be added to the management directory or is this structure purely vestigial?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the history, but it seems semi-vestigial to me. As for other stuff that can be put in the management dir, the comment about signals above hints at one answer.

One thing I do when trying to answer such questions is to look at the contrib apps to see what they do. Some interesting bits to be found:

- [`auth/management/__init__.py`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py)
- [`sites/management.py`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/sites/management.py)

Note that in the second one, the management module is a .py file rather than a directory.

Answer (score 3):

Another thing that needs to be placed in the `management` module (either in `management/__init__.py` or `management.py`) is any listeners to the `django.db.models.signals.post_sync` signal.

Answer (score -2):

It is a skeleton of django's general design.  Almost every project will contain multiple apps, so the project is really a container of apps with a shared configuration.

You can add other items to the project level folder, but the design suggests only high level cross-app items should be.  Examples are urls and settings.