# django directory structure of module for commands

Tags: django, django-models, django-commands

in django 1.6, I have a commands for make analysis over the database, with a set of functions.

```
├── management
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── commands
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── analysis.py
```

I like break the analysis.py in a set of files (maybe a module ...).
what is the correct directory structure for a module use for a django command ?

maybe like this ... ?

```
├── management
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── analysis_module
│   └── commands
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── analysis.py
```

and the test for the `analysis_module`, what is the correct ubication for the test of `analysis_module` ?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836075/are-there-any-purposes-for-the-management-folder-in-django-other-than-commands) implies that the `management` directory is not much used, so I doubt there's any risk to putting your common code there.

Comment: If the analysis module is potentially reusable I would move it out of your app altogether and just import it in your `analysis.py` command. I like to keep django apps/modules and non-django/python modules separate where possible

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony yes, I'm thinking in a solution like you comment, and I added this as answer. but I not sure if is the correct way to import ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a option, put the code modude out of django project

```
├── analysis_module
├── test
├── django_project
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── management
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── commands
│   │   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │   │       └── analysis.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.pyc
│   │   └── views.py
│   └── django_proyect
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── settings.py
│       ├── urls.py
│       └── wsgi.py
```

but for this, I need add the module to path to the `sys.path` maybe in `manage.py`

```
# manage.py
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(__file__ + '/../../'))
```

and import from the analysis command

```
# analysis.py
import analysis_module
```

with this I can put the test for analysis_module separately.